# IE7 100% width anchor without set container width

Tags: html, css

How to set 100% width anchor without parent width in IE7? Works fine in IE8 and above

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/GVj6K/2/

HTML

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">bla</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">bla bla lorem ipsum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">bla bla </a></li>        
    </ul>
<div>
```

CSS

```
div{
 position:absolute;
}    

ul{
 list-style:none;
 margin:0; padding:0;
}

a{
 display:block;
 padding:5px 10px;  
 white-space:nowrap;
 width:auto;    
}    

a:hover{
 background-color:#f0f0f0;
}
```

Comment: Does your `div` need to be absolutely positioned? Doing so takes it out of the flow of the document and loses its width...

Comment: yes ... div needs to be with absolute position

Comment: Then you may need to involve JavaScript as the context for defining the width in CSS is missing.

Comment: there is solution for this with css .. but i forgot it

Comment: Could you explain what exactly doesn't work? I can't seem to find the difference from IE8 to IE7. Does the problem also occur in IE9 run as IE7?

Comment: clickable and hover area is different in IE7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a background color on the a tags:
http://jsfiddle.net/GVj6K/12/

```
a{
 display:block;
 padding:5px 10px;  
 white-space:nowrap;
 width:auto;
 background:#fff;
}
```

Or, you could use a tiled trans.gif

Comment: i play with height:1; on anchor and line-height:1; on LI.. works fine too .. but not in jsfiddle .. thx